# AWS EC2 Instance stopping right after start using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, ec2-ami

Using boto3 run_instances

The instance is stopping after 30 sec by itself and the State transition reason in the console shows:

```
Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check if your AMI type (PV or HVM) and the volumes are compatible and you are **mounting the volumes to the correct device**. If there is a compatibility issue, the instance shuts down with `Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown`

Comment: Thanks it worked, changed the OS of the AMI and the EC2 Linux mounts /dev/xvda and the old one was /dev/sda1